# Pickling a scraped list with BS4 vs Preset Data issue (why is it not working the same?)

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, pickle

I am trying to save this scraped data to file (pickle it) but I cannot figure out why I cannot pickle it with this code:

```
url = "https://www.imdb.com/list/ls016522954/?ref_=nv_tvv_dvd"

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')
dvdNames = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="lister-item-content")
for dvd in dvdNames:
    dvdArray.append(dvd.a.string)
viewtitles = input("Finished!, do you want to view the DVD titles? (Y/N): ")
if viewtitles == "y".casefold():
    num = 1
    for name in dvdArray:
        print(""+ str(num) + " - " + name)
        num += 1
elif viewtitles == "n".casefold():
    print("Not Showing TItles!")
else:
    print("that is not an option!")
saveToFile = input("Do you want to save / update the data? (Y/N): ")
if saveToFile == "y".casefold():
    with open("IMDBDVDNames.dat", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(dvdArray, f)
        continue
elif saveToFile == "n".casefold():
    print("Data Not Saved!")
    continue
else:
    print("That's not one of the option!")
    continue
```

I've tried adding the sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000) and it doesn't make a difference (FYI) and am getting this error "maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object" but when I run this code:

```
import pickle

testarray = []

if input("1 or 2?: ") == "1":
    testarray = ['1917', 'Onward', 'The Hunt', 'The Invisible Man', 'Human Capital', 'Dolittle', 'Birds of Prey: And the Fantabulous Emancipation of One Harley Quinn', 'The Gentlemen', 'Bloodshot', 'The Way Back', 'Clemency', 'The Grudge', 'I Still Believe', 'The Song of Names', 'Treadstone', 'Vivarium', 'Star Wars: Episode IX - The Rise of Skywalker', 'The Current War', 'Downhill', 'The Call of the Wild', 'Resistance', 'Banana Split', 'Bad Boys for Life', 'Sonic the Hedgehog', 'Mr. Robot', 'The Purge', 'VFW', 'The Other Lamb', 'Slay the Dragon', 'Clover', 'Lazy Susan', 'Rogue Warfare: The Hunt', 'Like a Boss', 'Little Women', 'Cats', 'Madam Secretary', 'Escape from Pretoria', 'The Cold Blue', 'The Night Clerk', 'Same Boat', 'The 420 Movie: Mary & Jane', 'Manou the Swift', 'Gold Dust', 'Sea Fever', 'Miles Davis: Birth of the Cool', 'The Lost Husband', 'Stray Dolls', 'Mortal Kombat Legends: Scorpions Revenge', 'Just Mercy', 'The Righteous Gemstones', 'Criminal Minds', 'Underwater', 'Final Kill', 'Green Rush', 'Butt Boy', 'The Quarry', 'Abe', 'Bad Therapy', 'Yip Man 4', 'The Last Full Measure', 'Looking for Alaska', 'The Turning', 'True History of the Kelly Gang', 'To the Stars', 'Robert the Bruce', 'Papa, sdokhni', 'The Rhythm Section', 'Arrow', 'The Assistant', 'Guns Akimbo', 'The Dark Red', 'Dreamkatcher', 'Fantasy Island', 'The Etruscan Smile', "A Nun's Curse", 'Allagash']
    with open("test.dat", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(testarray, f)
else:
    with open("test.dat", "rb") as f:
        testarray = pickle.load(f)

print(testarray)
```

with the exact same (at least I hope it's the same, I did a print(dvdArray) and got the list that way FYI) information but it WILL let me pickle it when i do it like that

can someone let me know why and how I can fix it?

I know I'm scraping the data from a website and converting it into a list but cannot figure out what is causing the error in example 1 vs example 2

any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

lttlejiver

Answer (score 0):

In Case anyone is curious, I added "strip()" to when I was appending the dvdArray and it worked!

```
dvdArray.append(dvd.a.string.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup objects are highly recursive, and so are very difficult to pickle. When you do `dvdArray.append(dvd.a.string)`, `dvd.a.string` is not a python string, but a `bs4.element.NavigableString` - one of these complex objects. By using `strip()`, you're actually converting the `bs4.element.NavigableString` to a python string, which is easily pickled. The same would be true if you used `dvd.a.getText()`.

For future reference, when pickling, always remember to convert (where possible) BeautifulSoup objects to simpler python objects.